# Как выделять активный пункт меню при сборке проекта с помощью fileinclude?

Tags: gulp, npm, сборка

Есть многостраничная верстка, она собирается по частям, подключается шапка, футер и тд, нужно, чтобы активный пункт подсвечивался автоматически. Т.е есть какой-то класс который отвечает за активное состояние ссылки например `.link-active`, если собирается главная, то присвоить этот класс пункту меню определенному и так далее. Знаю, что это можно как-то сделать в gulp-file-include, но не знаю как.

Comment: тут кажется то, что вы ищете  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127143/gulp-file-include-and-navbar-class-active